# How to type the | character of the normal size in text mode?

Tags: symbols, text-mode

I dont want to use rule because its long and hideous and I must do it in text mode. Any solutions?

Comment: Please be more specific. Rule means something specific in LaTeX and it does not have a predefined length/width. So please extend your question, preferably with an MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: although I posted an answer your question isn't really understandable, what does "long and hideous" mean.  a `\rule{3cm}{1pt}` is exactly 3cm long, if the rule you are getting is too long, specify a shorter length.

Comment: Maybe an en-dash is more suitable (`abc -- def`)? It is half the size of `|` (and `---`).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown what you did, but in most sensible encodings you can type `|`to get |  (this doesn't apply to the default OT1 encoding, but there are few good reasons to use that).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

a|b
\end{document}
```